# drinking natural diuretics for fluid recommendations

Tags: water, natural-remedy, water-retention, diuretics

Yeo's Chrysanthemum Tea Drink makes me urinate. A lot. I could easily drink enough of the stuff to satisfy the daily fluid intake recommendations. However, the more I drink, the more often I have to go.. It feels like drinking the tea, or any other fluids that are natural diuretics, as fluid intake would be counterproductive. Is this true?

*PS: Ingredients are water, aqueous extract of chrysanthemum, and cane sugar. And  yes, it would be healthier if I brew it myself and use honey or a non glucose/fructose sweetener, but I'm not asking if there is a healthier tea.*

[image]